# Delete .mobile.navigate.history.stack jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, history, back

Hi i am new for jquery mobile . I got 3 pages in my apps. Page1.html,page2.html and popup.html. Page2 allow user navigate to popup.html to select item adding record into page2.html.

So now is my problem when i in page2.html go to popup.html then popup.html back to page2.html . When press back button in page2.html will back to popup.html. Is it possible to skip back to popup.html directly back to page1.html?